# I want to change the logout URL of the default button in Spring Boot Admin, and nothing else

Tags: spring-boot-admin

What is the best way to change the default logout behaviour of Spring Boot Admin? Currently everything else is working perfectly. I am using an OAuth2 security provider, and login works fine. Currently I am using the standard Spring Boot Admin defaults for everything, except that my application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.all-namespaces=false

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.---.jwk-set-uri=https://...
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.---.issuer-uri=https://...

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.---.client-id=client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.---.client-secret=secrect
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.---.client-name=client-name
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.---.scope=openid,client-name
```

The logout button currently performs a POST request to base_path/logout, which fails with a 403. (Sidetrack: if it was a GET it would successfully logout of Spring Boot Admin, but that is not exactly what I want since it does not logout of the security provider.) What I want is for it to direct me to the logout url for my OAuth2 security provider.

**What is the best way to change nothing but the url that the logout button directs me to?**

I have already tried a few things, (though I don't think most were noteworthy since they didn't work), including

```
@Configuration
public class SBAdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl(
                "{oauth2 logout URL placeholder}?post_logout_redirect_uri={sba base url placeholder}%2Flogout"));

    }
}
```

This does not work because it removes all other security configuration, including whatever default WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has already been configured behind the scenes. With this, when I try to go to my Spring Boot Admin app, there is no security at all.

I suspect a way to solve this would be to copy whatever existing configuration is being done by imported libraries into my own WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and edit it slightly to change the logout URL. However I have not been able to find anything to tell me where this existing configuration is or what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to logout from Spring Boot application first and redirect the logout success url to OAuth2 security provider logout url.

Sample configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/oauth2/logouturl/here");
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks, but I have already tried just redirecting the logout. I had tried the same as you have shown except `logout -> logout.logoutUrl("{oauth2_logout_url}?post_logout_redirect_uri={spring_boot_admin_url}%2Flogout"` instead of logoutSuccessUrl. Now I've also tried your suggestion. It does not solve my problem.

My problem is that this seems to override whatever other WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has been set up. I no longer have the OAuth2 login handling, the default login page, or the logout button. I am looking for the best way to change the logout URL without changing anything else

Comment: I will revise my question with this clarification. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Check this sample code. It uses different url to perform logout. You have to update your logout button url the same
[Sample configuration](https://github.com/Elyorbe/bibliotheca/blob/master/src/main/java/tech/ibrokhimov/bibliotheca/web/security/WebSecurityConfig.java#L59-L68)